# kaMapCache with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers

i am trying to use the kaMapCache layer to improve the performance of my web map. the kaMapCache layer generate the images at the specific scales but i can't make openlayers use those images to make the map faster.

thaks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've tried a lot to do that but i never find any way to do it...

searching a little i found this:

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Precaching-ka-map-layers-td3964678.html

you should try it...

Comment: thank's Ricardo ABC. i've tried that code and the map its better now becouse once i've charged the map the application is faster